# How can I retrieve the top three amounts within a specific time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging

I'm trying to retrieve the top 3 likes of this past week from the `uploads` table.  Ideally, I'm going to execute this query every Thursday at the end of day but for some reason, my query below is returning nothing but empty columns.

A screenshot's attached of the format of the timestamp

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
select `users`.`name`, `uploads`.`likes`, `uploads`.`url`, `uploads`.`UserID`, `users`.`email`, `uploads`.`timestamp`
from `uploads`
inner join `users`
on `users`.`UserID` = `uploads`.`UserID`
where `uploads`.`timeStamp` >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) +6 DAY
and `uploads`.`timeStamp` < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) -1 DAY
order by `likes`
desc limit 3;
```

Comment: of the data you show, only the 2023-01-07 row is in the past week you are selecting.  it should be returned, unless its UserID is not in the users table.

Comment: @ysth it is indeed in the user's table.  that's what's confusing about this

Comment: Just to make sure, run the query without the `WHERE` section and tell us if there are results.

Comment: @FanoFN oh ok, I get results! But they aren't this week's results

Comment: Then you can run each of the `WHERE` starting with the first condition and try to find out which condition making the results empty.

Comment: By the way, you can run `SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) +6 DAY, CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) -1 DAY` and see the value it returns then compare with your table to determine whether there are data between these dates.

Comment: @sp92 if the results without the `WHERE` aren't from this week, then you should select from the uploads table only and look if there are entries from this week.

Comment: your calculated dates are for the Sunday to Saturday week ending the Saturday before today.  if that is not the week you want, please be more explicit than "this week" / "this past week".